# How can I host the Ulympics?

Tags: venture-towns

I really would like to host the Ulympics. I suspect I need a lot of money and possibly certain buildings, as I failed getting to host them this time. I have four years to sort myself out and make my city awesome enough to host.

What do I need to do or have to be able to host the Ulypmics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there's still some research going on to find the exact formula used to determine if you host the Ulympics. However, the minimum successful configuration found so far is:

Jobs:

- 1 Athelete
- 1 Entrepreneur
- 1 Politician

Buildings:

- 1 TV Station
- 1 Sports Combo
- 1 Security Company

[Source](http://www.kairospot.net/venture-towns-guide)